# Should I place elastic beanstalk options under Configuration Files (.ebextensions) or Saved Configurations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use CLI to configure the load balancer set up by elastic beanstalk.

However, I'm not sure if I should place the option [`aws:elbv2:listener:443:`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2-listener) in *Configuration Files (.ebextensions)* or *Saved Configurations*.

Are there any guidelines or conventions about when to place options under *Saved Configurations* and *Configuration Files (.ebextensions)*?

The official document [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence) only tells me the precedence of the two places.

> Saved Configurations – Settings for any options that are not applied
>   directly to the environment are loaded from a saved configuration, if
>   specified.
>
> Configuration Files (.ebextensions) – Settings for any options that
>   are not applied directly to the environment, and also not specified in
>   a saved configuration, are loaded from configuration files in the
>   .ebextensions folder at the root of the application source bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-before.html) says:

> Use .ebextensions to configure options that are required to make your
>   application work, and provide default values for other options that
>   can be overridden at a higher level of precedence.

and

> Create a saved configuration to save settings that you have applied to
>   an existing environment during or after environment creation